Is pressure only define at the surface in contact?
Is pressure only defined at the surface of an object or a container in contact with the fluid as per the definition of pressure,

Pressure is the force applied perpendicular to the surface of an object per unit area over which that force is distributed. (Wikipedia)


Is pressure undefined at the point D in the above figure. If we take a measuring instrument at point D, then, the fluid will be in contact with the instrument so here pressure will become defines. But speaking without any instrument, will it be defined?

The definition that you quote from the top of the Wikipedia article applies to pressure on a surface, but further down in the article there is another definition:

Fluid pressure is ... the compressive stress at some point within a fluid.

Using this definition, there is a definite fluid pressure at point $D$, regardless of whether or not we are measuring it.

If the container is rigid, then hydrostatic pressures on the container due to the fluid outside the container (A,B,C) are independent of the hydrostatic pressure of the fluid within the container (D).
Hope this helps.
